# At runtime, get number of parameters/arguments passed to a method, with or without varargs, in Java

Tags: java, parameters, arguments, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

Background:

I am porting code from another language. In that language, **trailing arguments are always optional**. A method like: `doIt( String x , Integer y , UUID z )` may be called with zero, one, two, or three arguments passed.

So that language offers a `countArguments` function. When translating code from that language to Java, I need a function in Java to substitute every occurrence of `countArguments`.

---

With modern Java, is there some way to get a count of parameters or arguments passed to a method?

### Method overloading

We have [method overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), each taking a different number of arguments. Example:

- `doIt( String x )`
- `doIt( String x , Integer y )`
- `doIt( String x , Integer y , UUID z )`

### Varargs

And we have [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html):

- `doIt( String x , Integer y , UUID z , BigDecimal... )`

### Get count of arguments

➥ How to get the actual number of arguments passed at runtime?

Example:

```
public void doIt( String x ) {
    int countArguments = … ;  // Returns `1`. 
}

public void doIt( String x , Integer y ) {
    int countArguments = … ;  // Returns `2`.
}

public void doIt( String x , Integer y , UUID z , BigDecimal... ) {
    int countArguments = … ;  // Returns `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, or more.
}
```

Comment: Mmmh I'm not entirely sure I'm getting the question. Where would you want to place this "check"? And by that I mean that it's not like Javascript where you can basically throw in what you want.

Comment: And what about this is unique to Java 11?

Comment: @shmosel Nothing. Simply noting that I am not limited to older Java versions.

Comment: @BasilBourque Each method has a well defined number of arguments. For the varargs one, it's just an array, so look for the length property.

Comment: For the example count will be 3+varArgs.length

Comment: @LppEdd I added a note at the bottom. This is about translating code from another language. I need a function in Java that I can drop into place when translating code in the other language calling a `getCountArguments` command.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Can you demonstrate what it would look like in the original language?

Comment: @BasilBourque what do you want the function's signature to be? Do you want to explicitly specify the fixed number of arguments, at least, or you just want to call getCountArguments(this) ?

Comment: @shmosel In the original language, any of the trailing arguments are optional. ⬅ Thanks for the questions, to clarify the problem -- my prior sentence sums up the issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque what's the original language?

Comment: But in Java they're not...

Comment: @LppEdd The other language is quite obscure, and I would rather not say.

Comment: @shmosel True, as you say, arguments are not optional in Java (nulls are passed instead, in some APIs). But nevertheless it is not *forbidden* in Java to ask the number of arguments, is it? I am attempting to auto-translate a code base, so I need to replace every function in the other language, and that includes this `countArguments` function.

Comment: @BasilBourque It is not *forbidden*, it is simply *unsupported*.

Comment: If you're translating code, then you've parsed the code, and you know what method you're in. If the method doesn't have varargs, replace `countArguments` with the number of declared parameters. If the method has a varargs, then replace `countArguments` with formula `(N + VARARG.length)` where N is number of declared parameters minus 1, and `VARARG` is the name of the varargs parameter.

Comment: What about using an aspectj for example?

Answer (score 1):

Partly it can be done using reflection. Using [`getEnclosingMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingMethod--):

```
public void doIt(String x, Integer y, BigDecimal... decimals) {
    int count = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getParameterCount();  // 3
}
```

But note, since varargs is an array it will be considered as 1 argument. To get length of this array you need to get value. But you can't get any values using reflection. In this case probably better to use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) as suggested by @LppEdd

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about converting from e.g. JavaScript, where function arguments are undefined, and you only have 1 function with a given name, so you have to check the number of arguments actually passed to figure out which "overload" of the function is called, then your method should be translated to:

```
doIt(Object... args)
```

The length of the array is the number of arguments.

Of course, that's how you do it in JavaScript, because the arguments are undefined, and there is no overload.

In Java, you should create actually overloaded methods, with different argument lists, as you showed in the question. In those methods, there is no need to check the number of arguments, because the argument list is fixed.

Having code that checks the number of arguments when the method knows exactly how many there are (because they are fixed), is ridiculous, so the question makes no sense, in a non-varargs Java context.

**Final Answer:**
If method has varargs, then check the length of the array.
If method doesn't have varargs, then a check of argument count is idiotic, and the code shouldn't do it.

Comment: I think he wants something totally automated, without having to pass arguments explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Use `AspectJ` with an `Around` or `Before` advice.
You'll get a `JoinPoint`, simply call `JoinPoint#getArgs();`.

```
final Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
final int count = arguments.length;
```

Voilà.

---

**Old answer.**

> I am porting code from another language with this feature. I need a
>   way to emulate this "count arguments" function. I need a function in
>   Java to substitute for calls made to such a function

This is not worth it. What you'd have to do to make this totally automatic is

1. Get Stack trace (`Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`)
2. Get calling *method name*, one level up, and *line number*
3. Parse the class with a bytecode manipulation tool such as `ByteBuddy` or `ASM` to find the actual method arguments.
4. Pass the varargs, when they're present, as input to *this* method (the method I'm actually describing).
5. Sum the arguments found via parsing the .class with the varargs length.

No other ways. But this is suicidal